# Modernizr - html5shiv w/printshiv

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr, html5shiv

When make one's own build of [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) you're given an option for `html5shiv 3.7` or `html5shiv 3.7.1 w/printshiv`.

Can anyone explain the difference between these two options? I couldn't find it in the documentation for Modernizr and had little luck searching Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description available [**here**](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv#readme),

```
html5shiv-printshiv.js
```

> This includes all of the above, as well as a mechanism allowing HTML5
>   elements to be styled and contain children while being printed in IE
>   6-8.

Comment: so why would anyone not want that?

Comment: printshiv takes care of the printing of the web page in ie < 9, so that when the web page is printed on the paper, it should appear user-friendly. So, if it's a requirement for you, then you need to include it. Or else, you can proceed with html5shiv 3.7 only.

Comment: A better answer to your question would be - If you are sure that no one would print any section of your website, then you should not want printshiv.